# What is causing this html5 video glitch?

Tags: css, html, video, html5-video

I have an html5 video tag with a div that has a text caption overlayed and when you scroll in chrome, the text div disappears as it gets near the top or bottom of the screen fold. Sometimes it's as its nearing the top of the screen, sometimes the bottom. I think it depends where the video is on the screen when it's refreshed.

Anyone know what is causing this? I think this is pretty barebones markup.

codepen: https://codepen.io/sharpdesigner/pen/KRgQZZ

screen capture of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcClb.jpg

html

```
<section id="video-landing" class="hide-mobile">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 video-caption">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
                            <p class="big">Quisque varius erat et</p>
                            <p>Vivamus aliquam lectus est. Nulla vitae fringilla felis. Aenean id elit sit amet sem mattis bibendum eu a felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>

                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div> <!-- /container -->

                    <video muted autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="bgvid">
                            <source src="http://www.mysportresume.com/phone.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
                    </video>

                </section><!-- #section -->
```

css

```
body {
  height: 2000px;
  margin-top: 500px;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
section#video-landing, section#video-landing-mobile {
    background: url('../images/video-bg.jpg') no-repeat 0 -175px;
    background-size: cover;
}
section#video-landing .row, section#video-landing-mobile .row {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.video-caption {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 550px;
    top: 165px;
    top: 8.5vw;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
.video-caption h1, .video-caption p {
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
}
.video-caption h1 {
    font-size: 53px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.video-caption p.big {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    max-width: 400px;
}
.video-caption p {
    font-size: 17px;
}
p.big {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 27px !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.5;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
video {
  padding-top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-55%);
  width: 100%;
}
#video-landing, #video-landing-mobile {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
#video-landing .container, #video-landing-mobile .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
}
#video-landing video, #video-landing-mobile video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this with the provided codepen. Is chrome up to date? have you tried disabling hardware accelerated rendering?

Comment: "Google Chrome is up to date
Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)"
I also just disabled hardware acceleration and restarted chrome but the issue is still here. It's also here for a co-worker on another computer. Both using Windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: I doubled checked I was using version 65.0.3325.181, I'm also on win 7 64. After updating I get the same issue, I'd try submitting the a bug to google.

Comment: Yeah, if it's a chome bug then I guess I have to just live with it. I just want to make sure it's not something in the code.